# IE 11 bootstrap 4 flexbox width issue when overflow-y scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have created a minimal example to reproduce the problem I am having with IE 11 and `flex-box` width when overflow-y scroll is enabled.

As soon as the the scroll-bar appears IE 11 does not render the `main` div with the correct width. As soon as I resize the browser window it renders correctly.

I have tested on chrome and Edge and it is working as expected.

You can find the example [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/2X03Z6rfgowI04eH?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

This is how IE 11 renders it the first time:

[image]

And this is how it is rendered as soon as I resize the window or open the dev tools:

[image]

The source code is [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/2X03Z6rfgowI04eH?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Please view the example in IE 11

```
<style>
    .left {
        align-items: center;
        color: #deebff;
        background-color: #0747a6;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 64px;
        padding: 16px 0px;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .main {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
    }

    .menu {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
</style>

<div style="display: flex">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="menu"></div>
        <div style="width: 100%;    display: flex;    max-height: 100vh;    overflow-y: auto;    padding: 25px;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        col1
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br /> test
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        col2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        col3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you put a display:flex in a container-fluid parent, but if you remove it, IE11 says "Aaah, now I understand what you really want from me, man. Excuse me!" :P

Try this with IE11, with mine it works well.

```css
.left {
            align-items: center;
            color: #deebff;
            background-color: #0747a6;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 64px;
            padding: 16px 0px;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .main {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            
        }

        .menu {
            display: flex;
            flex: 1 0 auto;
            
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
        <div style="display: flex">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="menu"></div>
            <div style="width: 100%;       max-height: 100vh;    overflow-y: auto;    padding: 25px;">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                            col1
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br /> test
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                            col2
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                            col3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

Instead, if display:flex; is very important for you, you can also add "flex:1" to 'container-fluid'

```css
.left {
            align-items: center;
            color: #deebff;
            background-color: #0747a6;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 64px;
            padding: 16px 0px;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .main {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            
        }

        .menu {
            display: flex;
            flex: 1 0 auto;
        
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
     <div style="display: flex">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="menu"></div>
            <div style="width: 100%;   display:flex; max-height: 100vh;    overflow-y: auto;    padding: 25px;">
                <div class="container-fluid" style="flex:1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                            col1
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br /> test
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                            col2
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                            col3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```